# What happens in HR after manager hands out a verbal offer?

Tags: job-offer, human-resources

My potential future manager followed up with me after an interview and hands out a "verbal offer"(We didn't talk about compensation or benefits, he was ensuring that I am still available, interested in the position and mentioned that the interview process will be waived once I applied online) The manager mentioned there is going to be a delay on the official offer as the HR is not ready to post the job on the website yet.
I'm really curious what that means and what happens in HR after manager gives a verbal offer to a candidate? As I am not familiar with the HR process.

It's been two weeks since I last spoken with the manager, and I saw the HR department checked my website last week and opened every page on the website. I understand it usually takes awhile for HR to hands out an official offer especially around the holiday season but I thought all those background checks come after a candidate accepted the offer. Am I just being held as a backup while they're waiting to hear from other candidates?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

### "You Know Nothing [Yet], Jon Snow!"

> My potential future manager followed up with me after an interview and hands out a verbal offer...The manager mentioned there is going to be a delay on the official offer as the HR is not ready to post the job on the website yet.

It's impossible to read too much into a situation where one wasn't present, so your mileage may vary. However, this happens often enough that one can make some reasonable assumptions based on life experience. More pragmatically, it means that the following are all equally likely to be true:

1. The manager liked you enough to want to make sure you were still on the market before recommending a candidate to HR.
2. The manager probably didn't intend to make a "verbal offer," but rather was giving you positive feedback that you'd made the short list from which the final selection would actually be made.
3. The manager probably recommended that you be made an offer, if you said you were still available and interested.
4. This particular manager is likely not the actual hiring authority.
5. The manager was hiring you ahead of a posting (which can be a good thing), but it can also mean the manager had no backing to actually hire anyone.
6. The hiring process will unwind at a pace that neither the hiring manager nor you can directly control.
7. You do *not* actually have a real offer yet.
8. You do not yet have an actual job with them.
9. You do not yet know the parameters of any possible offer, including wages or benefits.
10. You have no timeline expectations from the employer, so you have no way to know if (among other possibilities) the delay is routine, they're waiting on budget or headcount approval for the role, you're still just one candidate among many, or if it's something else altogether.

Basically, you have questions, and random strangers on the Internet can't really tell you what the employer's standard process is or what's in their minds. While it's likely that you're in a holding pattern until the end of the year, if you want to know what your status is or what their timeline is for providing you with an offer, you'll have to *ask* them.

It's not at all unreasonable to reach out to the manager (or the human resources department, depending on the politics) and ask something like:

> Thanks for the feedback you gave me a few weeks ago. Will I be receiving an offer? If so, when should I expect an offer to be extended?

You can gussy it up and make it more polite (or more demanding, if you prefer) but in the end you are simply asking that they define their process and a time box for you. That's not at all unreasonable, and is really the only way you will get a definitive answer to your very reasonable process-related questions.

Comment: This smells like 5 to me.  Manager has a business need now, wants to make a case that has a great candidate if they move now that probably wont be available when they are ready after (fiscal year end) when execs are willing to reopen hiring.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm really curious what that means and what happens in HR after
>   manager gives a verbal offer to a candidate?

I think your case, based on my experience, *the manager meant exactly what he said*.  He wants to hire you and is waiting on HR to catch up.  I would give it a week, and then reach back out to the manager and check on the status.

Another point, **do not give your notice to your current employer until you have the official offer letter** from the company AND you have met any conditions that may come with it.  ( like a drug test for example )

Answer (score 0):

HR has to put together the benefit package and the offer financially. They sometimes have to deal with other managers and Finance to get the right amount approved.

They may be determining what pay scale your experience qualifies you for and where in the salary range of that payscale do they think you will fit.  If you have asked for more than their payscale for a Dev1, they may be deciding if you can qualify for a Dev2 and if the budget is there for such a thing. Often what HR wants to pay, what Finance says they can pay and what the manager wants to pay are at odds and these things require negotiation.

They may be checking with other people involved in the interview process to make sure all of them want to hire you.  They need to make sure the vacancy can still be filled (things like company wide hiring freezes happen or changes to the budget). They may be checking references. Background checks could happen if they have already had you fill out the forms for such.

At this time of year (the question was asked in Dec), the people they need to discuss things with may be on vacation as many companies have use or lose vacation time.  In fact, if you are in a mostly Christian country, it may be very unlikely they will get the offer out until next year due to that.

The 2017 budget for new hires might be used up or possibly some things from the 2018 budget are not yet set. Such as whether there is any budget at all due to the government not approving their budget  and putting a stop to all government contracts for instance. They may even delay if they are in the process of setting up a layoff or hiring freeze that the hiring manager is not yet aware of. They generally won't make an offer until they know they have the budget to hire you.

Or they may be busy with other tasks like setting up the 2018 benefits for the whole company or a corporate merger or filling a higher priority vacancy.